# Issue selecting timespan values in KDB

Tags: kdb

I  am facing an issue while selecting the following following timespan :

```
t:([] date:2#.z.d ; time: 10D21:28:47.425287000 10D12:18:23.287989000 )

date       time                 
--------------------------------
2018.03.15 10D21:28:47.425287000
2018.03.15 10D12:18:23.287989000
```

when i run the following query, i am not getting the second record back

```
select from t where time within (12:00;13:00)
```

I am expecting the 2nd record from the table :

```
date       time                
-------------------------------
2018.03.15 10D12:18:23.287989000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `10` in the time value `10D12:18:23.287989000` intentional ?

The reason behind the data not coming back is the time (type timespan )  is actually not the nano seconds since  midnight  ; as per the  table it is **10 days plus** nanos since midnight

To select the data only on the basis of time :

```
q)select  from t where (`time$(`date$0)+time) within (12:00;13:00)
date       time                
-------------------------------
2018.03.15 10D12:18:23.287989000
```

Try adding the date and time from the table , you would see the date forwarded  by 10 days

```
q)select date+time from t

date                         
-----------------------------
2018.03.25D21:28:47.425287000
2018.03.25D12:18:23.287989000
```

The timespan is basically `nDhh:mm:ss.sssssssss` , where n is relative to midnight. If its 0 then it's current day otherwise its `+/- n days` (depending on whether n is positive or negative).

try running the following , it will return you the difference between the 2 timestamps as a timespan with `n=10`.

```
q)2018.03.25D10:12:00.000000000 - 2018.03.15D10:00:00.000000000   
10D00:12:00.000000000
```

Comment: `10` is actually unintentional, seems like the `nanos` i am storing is messing up, it should be `0D12:18:23.287989000`. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Although you should fix your timestamps (there shouldn't be a 10D) if you're in a situation where you can't fix the upstream data but you believe the timestamps to actually be correct, then you can strip away the 10D as follows:

```
q)update mod[;`long$10D]time from t
date       time
-------------------------------
2018.03.16 0D21:28:47.425287000
2018.03.16 0D12:18:23.287989000
```